# My mod can't toggle mouse buttons while alt+f4. What's causing this and how can I fix this?

Tags: minecraft-forge

MC version: 1.8.9

```
public static void EnableAutoFarm(){
   KeyBinding.setKeyBindState(mc.gameSettings.keyBindAttack.getKeyCode(), true); // statement a
   KeyBinding.setKeyBindState(mc.gameSettings.keyBindRight.getKeyCode(), true); // statement b
}
```

So I have been coding a afk mod that can auto farm crops. The server I made it for restarts every 12 hours. To counter this I made a system that will activate auto farm after server restart and reconnecting. This will all happen while mc window is alt+f4'ed. Normally when I manually activate the auto farm while in focus with mc window **statement a** and **statement b** works perfectly fine even after alt+f4. But when I alt+f4 and it gets disconnected because of server restart it auto reconnects and then auto warps back to the farm and then it runs **EnableAutoFarm()** method. In that situation auto farm method's **statement a** won't work even tho the state is set to true but the **statement b** works perfectly fine tho. What could be causing this?

Extra info:
F3 + P is enabled so it doesn't loose focus while alt+f4'ed
Statement a and b automatically sets to false when it disconnects because of the method I made.

Answer (score 0):

alt+f4 will exit the game completely by default on your computer. So you would need to find a different key combination to do what you are trying to do.